# $\|ta+(1-t)b\|^2=t\|a\|^2+(1-t)\|b\|^2-t(1-t)\|a-b\|^2$, Is that true?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $\|\cdot\|$ be the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R^n}$,

My question is do we always have for all $t\in [0,1]$ , the following identity ?
$$\|ta+(1-t)b\|^2=t\|a\|^2+(1-t)\|b\|^2-t(1-t)\|a-b\|^2$$

I tried to test it for $t=1/2$ and it gives me the parallelogram identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identity can be proved by noting that $||x||^2 = x\cdot x$, hence we have

$$\begin{align}
||ta+(1-t)b||^2 &= (ta+(1-t)b)\cdot (ta+(1-t)b) \\
&= t^2 a\cdot a + 2t(1-t)a\cdot b + (1-t)^2 b \cdot b \\
&=   ta\cdot a + (1-t)b\cdot b-t(1-t)a\cdot a - t(1-t)b\cdot b) + 2t(1-t)a\cdot b\\
&=  ta\cdot a + (1-t)b\cdot b-t(1-t)(a\cdot a - 2a\cdot b + b\cdot b) \\
&= ta\cdot a + (1-t)b\cdot b-t(1-t)(a-b)\cdot (a-b) \\
&=t||a||^2+(1-t)||b||^2-t(1-t)||a-b||^2
\end{align}$$